# Are there any estimates for the spectral radius and distribution of eigenvalues for the AES, DES, etc round functions?

Tags: encryption, symmetric

Suppose that $F:K\times X\rightarrow X$ is a function such that for each $k\in K$, the mapping $F_{k}:X\rightarrow X$ defined by letting $F_{k}(x)=F(k,x)$ is a bijection. Suppose that $F$ is the round function for some cryptographic function such as a block cipher or cryptographic hash function. Let $V_{X}$ be the complex vector space consisting of all tuples $(\alpha_{x})_{x\in X}$ such that $\sum_{x\in X}\alpha_{x}=0$. Define an irreducible linear representation of $\phi$ the permutation group $S_{X}$ on $V_{X}$ by letting $\phi(f)(\alpha_{x})_{x\in X})=(\alpha_{f(x)})_{x\in X}$.

Define a linear transformation $L_{F}=\sum_{k\in K}\phi(F_{k})$.

If the permutations $F_{k}$ are random and independently selected, then the [circular law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law) seems to hold for the linear transformation $L_{F}$, so the eigenvalues of $L_{F}$ should be approximately uniformly distributed on the disk $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|^{2}\leq |K|\}$, and the spectral radius of $L_{F}$ should be around $\sqrt{|K|}$. Of course, in practice the round functions $F_{k}$ are non-random for block cipher round functions $F$. It seems like it would be good to try to make the spectral radius of $L_{F}$ quite low in order to make the random variables $Z_{n}$ as uniform on $X^{2}$ as possible where the value of $Z_{n}$ is a random pair $(x,y)$ where $x$ is selected from $X$ uniformly at random and $y=F_{k_{1}}\dots F_{k_{n}}(x)$ for randomly and independently selected $k_{1},\dots,k_{n}\in K$.

Now, there are some instances where $L_{F}$ is nilpotent for rather trivial reasons. For example, if $F(k,x)=k\oplus g(x)$ for some permutation $g$ (as is the case with AES), then $L_{F}$ is nilpotent. One could also ensure that $L_{F}$ is nilpotent for some Feistel cipher block functions $F$.

Is there any computation or estimate of the spectral radius or distribution of eigenvalues of $L_{F}$ for the round functions for SHA-256 or any other modern block cipher or cryptographic hash function $F$ where $L_{F}$ is not nilpotent?

**Mathematics terminology**

$S_{X}$ is the group of all permutations from $X$ to $X$.

If $V,W$ are vector spaces, then let $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ be the set of all linear transformations $L:V\rightarrow W$. If $G$ is a group, and $V$ is a vector space, then a linear representation
of $G$ on the vector space $V$ is a function $\phi:G\rightarrow\text{Hom}(V,V)$ such that $\phi(g)\circ\phi(h)=\phi(gh)$ whenever $g,h\in G$. We say that $\phi$ is irreducible there does not exist a proper non-trivial subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $\phi(g)(w)\in W$ whenever $w\in W$.

If $A$ is a square matrix, then an eigenvalue of $A$ is a scalar $\lambda$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$ for some non-zero vector $\mathbf{x}$.

If $A$ is a square matrix with real or complex entries, then define the spectral radius $\sigma(A)$ of $A$ to be $$\max\{|\lambda|:\text{$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$}\}.$$

Suppose that $K$ is the field of real or complex numbers and $V$ is a vector space over the field $K$. A norm on a vector space $V$ is a function $\|\cdot\|:V\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ such that if $\alpha\in K,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in V$, then

1. $\|\alpha\cdot\mathbf{x}\|=|\alpha|\cdot\|\mathbf{x}\|,$
2. $\mathbf{x}\neq 0$ if and only if $\|\mathbf{x}\|>0$, and
3. $\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|\leq\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$.

It turns out that the spectral radius is always
$$\sigma(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\|A^{n}\|}$$
regardless of the norm chosen.

We say that an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is nilpotent if it satisfies one of the following properties:

1. $A^{n}=0$.
2. $A^{k}=0$ for some $k$.
3. All the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$.
4. The spectral radius of $A$ is $0$.

Comment: I had to edit the question to exclude the case where $L_{F}$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Whilst not a mathy person, I don't recognise many of the terms/concepts you're using. Might this be more suitable for Maths Overflow ( with only a small relevance to cryptography?) Our focus on round functions is principally to do with metrics of confusion and diffusion.

Comment: I have added some mathematical terminology. The spectral radius $\sigma(L_{F})$ of $L_{F}$ is a measure of something like confusion since it measures how uniform the random variables $Z_{n}$ become as $n\rightarrow\infty$, but $\sigma(L_{F})$ may be hard to calculate or estimate.